# How to save state of Bottom Navigation Fragment - Android Navigation Component With a Single Nav Graph

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation, android-bottomnav

How do I save the state of each bottom navigation fragment while using Android Navigation Component JetPack.

I know there is a way to do it using an Navigation Extension provided by the Android Team - [Navigation Extension](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt).  - While it works, it requires you to create multiple nav_graph for each fragment and also does not have the back stack I want. Also, switching between fragment seems slow using their approach.

How do I do save the state using a single nav_graph and maintain each back stack.
I am following this tutorial and its working but not saving the state of each fragment. Each instance of the fragment is created on Click of the bottom nav item. - [Bottom Nav Tutorial Like Instagram And Youtube](http://I%20am%20following%20this%20tutorial%20-%20%5Bhttps://proandroiddev.com/android-navigation-component-similar-back-stack-like-instagram-youtube-and-more-cf299a617492%5D%5B1%5D)

**activity_home.xml**

```
<fragment //I get a warning here, when I change to FragmentContainerView, app crashes//
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_2"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_2" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:itemIconSize = "30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>
```

**menu/bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/feedRandomFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_bottom_nav_selector"
    android:title="@string/home"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/exploreAndSearchFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/explore_bottom_nav_selector"
    android:title="@string/global_explore"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/uploadChooseFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_upload"
    android:title="@string/upload"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/allChallengesFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/challenges_bottom_nav_selector"
    android:title="@string/challenges"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/profileCurrentUserFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile_bottom_nav_selector"
    android:title="@string/profile"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    />
```

**HomeActivity.kt**

```
 if(savedInstanceState==null){
       setUpBottomNavigationBarBase()
   }

private fun setUpBottomNavigationBarBase(){
    binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(Navigation.findNavController(this, 
    R.id.nav_host_fragment_2))
    binding.bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {item ->
        onNavDestinationSelected(item, Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_2))
    }
    binding.bottomNavigation.itemIconTintList = null
    binding.bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
        //do something
    }
}
```

According to the Tutorial, to Maintain backstack, we have to extend all bottom nav fragments from a util class BaseBottomTabFragment which I did and works well.

**BaseBottomFragment**

```
open class BaseBottomTabFragment : Fragment() {

var isNavigated = false

fun navigateWithAction(action: NavDirections) {
    isNavigated = true
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}

fun navigate(resId: Int) {
    isNavigated = true
    findNavController().navigate(resId)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    if (!isNavigated)
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            val navController = findNavController()
            if (navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.id != null) {
                findNavController().popBackStackAllInstances(
                    navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.id!!,
                    true
                )
            } else
                navController.popBackStack()
        }
}

private fun NavController.popBackStackAllInstances(destination: Int, inclusive: Boolean): Boolean {
    var popped: Boolean
    while (true) {
        popped = popBackStack(destination, inclusive)
        if (!popped) {
            break
        }
    }
    return popped
 }
}
```

So, All my bottom tab fragments extends from that util class - BaseBottomTabFragment like this :

```
class ExploreAndSearchFragment : BaseBottomTabFragment()
```

Also, accoriding to the tutorial, to maintain the state of fragment and avoid recreation, each fragment has to have a unique ID which I also did - Sadly, this does not stop the fragment from recreating onClick.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".fragments.main.bottomnav.home.view.FeedRandomFragment"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@color/white"
android:id="@+id/homeId">
```

I set a unique id to All fragment, but it didnt work. Please Help me!

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? If please do share the concept or the code. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As I had a similar problem, I copied the Navigation Advanced Sample from their [**GitHub page**](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples) and started troubleshooting.

My goal was to use multiple back stacks while having an Instagram-like bottom navigation bar. So I wanted to combine MAD Skills' tutorial [Navigation: Multiple back stacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Covu3fPA1nQ) with
Furkan Aşkın's [Instagram-like back stack guide](https://proandroiddev.com/android-navigation-component-similar-back-stack-like-instagram-youtube-and-more-cf299a617492).

As I implemented both components, the project compiled perfectly but multiple back stacks didn't seem to work as the states of the bottom tabs weren't saved. I double-checked the version to be **2.4.0-alpha01** or newer.

What ended up being the problem was secondary menuCategory defined in **menu items**:

> `android:menuCategory="secondary"`

This was probably overwriting the multiple back stacks expected behaviour and upon deleting the lines, multiple back stacks work perfectly. Also, redundant back stacks are removed while navigating in different bottom navigation top level fragments.